# Searchkick search method argument error after ruby upgrade to 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick, ruby-3

Update ruby version from 2.7.2 to 3.0.0, default Searchkick search behavior stopped working.

Error trace:

```
ArgumentError in ProductsAvailabilitiesController#index

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

searchkick (4.4.4) lib/searchkick/model.rb:43:in `searchkick_search'
...
```

Here is simple search method that works fine on ruby 2.7.2:

```
def search_method(query, page)
  search_options = {
    fields: [:name, :address, :comment],
    match: :word_middle,
    page: page,
    per_page: 10
  }

  search(query, search_options)
end
```

Here is my Gemfile.lock:

```
searchkick (4.4.4)
  activemodel (>= 5)
  elasticsearch (>= 6)
  hashie
elasticsearch (7.11.2)
  elasticsearch-api (= 7.11.2)
  elasticsearch-transport (= 7.11.2)
elasticsearch-api (7.11.2)
  multi_json
elasticsearch-transport (7.11.2)
  faraday (~> 1)
  multi_json
```

Is there a way ot fix this problem or it's a bug in gem sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ruby 3.0.0 changelog you will find an updates about:

[Changes in separation of positional and keyword arguments](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/)

As you see in your error trace, problem is in method `searchkick_search`.
Let's check it's [implementation](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/lib/searchkick/model.rb#L43) in searchkick gem sources. It contains argument ****options**:

```
 def searchkick_search(term = "*", **options, &block)
```

In ruby 2.7.2 hashes are automatically converted to a keyword arguments.
In ruby 3.0.0 not.
If you you want to keep this behaviour - add "**" to search method argument.

Simply change in your sources this:

```
 search(query, search_options_hash)
```

To this:

```
 search(query, **search_options_hash)
```